# Schematic review for STM32 basic development board

Tags: schematic, review

Could anyone look over the schematic design for this STM32 ([STM32F103C8](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103c8.pdf)) bluepill-style board and check if everything is correct? I'm unsure if I wired everything correctly or if I'm missing anything important.

Specifically, I'm concerned whether or not the boot circuit and micro USB connector are correct.

[image]

Comment: Have you read the datasheet and hardware design guide? Have you gone through for each and every pin that you connect to something? Including crystal, reset, boot, and supply pins? Your design has all the same flaws as the bluepill does, and if you search here your question might already be answered - apparently it's a thing to clone a bad product and ask EE.SE for a design review which generally leads to endless comment chains what is the correct way to do something.

Comment: One remark I would make: I hate the old style where you just dump all decoupling caps in a corner of the schematic and place them between + and GND. That's useless and says absolutely nothing. Instead place them near those pins in the schematic that they will be placed near in the PCB layout as well.

Comment: USB needs a pull-up on the dataline, 1.5K for full speed on D+. Does the STM have internal pull-ups for this? If not you need one. Otherwise the device won't enumerate.

Comment: Why are C7, C8 and C9 100pF?

Answer (score 1):

You can add capactiors for each Vdd pins according to STM32F10xxx hardware development board.

[image]

Also your two connector have same designator name, you should change it.

[image]